# Searching large lists

Tags: 2007, list

I have a list (approximately 1000 entries) loaded onto a site as list webpart. I would like to be able to search this list with a partial query (ie similar to find in excel or word). I have found a few solutions but none of them really meet my needs.

The text filter webpart for instance sounded like it would do the trick but it requires an exact match. I have found some javascripts code snippets that are able to do partial searches however it seems they only work on the currently visible list items.

Is this something that is possible in Sharepoint 2007?

Sincerely,
Anand

Comment: >The text filter webpart for instance sounded like it would do the trick but it requires an exact match. This is not entirely true: you can edit the webpart in SPD Designer and change the filter from EQ to CONTAINS. See here: http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't like promoting paid solutions, I can only say that I have used Roxority Filterzen in Sharepoint 2007 in the past and it delivered. If you are not looking for just OOTB solution, but paid solutions are considered as well, take a look at http://roxority.com/filterzen/. I am sure there will be many alternatives out there, but this is what I have used.

I am not affiliated with the company.

Comment: Hi yandr, thanks for the comment I will take a look at it however I must admit I was looking for something I could implement without any purchases. It just seems odd to me that there is no way to just search list items OOTB.

Comment: I don't wish to split hair, but you can always search the list using OOTB webparts. Filtering is another story.